# Telnet: Connection refused for specific port only. [CentOS 8]

Tags: centos, networking, telnet

I am trying to connect from one server to another through its IP address using `telnet` as following:

```
[root@01 ~]# telnet 10.10.7.7 6379
Trying 10.10.7.7...
telnet: connect to address 10.10.7.7: Connection refused
```

While I can telnet other ports successfully also the issue is not caused by firewall, since the firewall stopped on both servers. Also I can access the same port on different servers within the same network.

P.S: the server is pingable and reachable for the second one.

Any idea what is causing this?

[Update]

The port already open and Listening as shown here:

```
[root@1 redis]# netstat -tupln 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      58512/sshd          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:44321         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      47659/pmcd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4330            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      44924/pmlogger      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      58878/redis-server
```

Comment: Even though firewall is open ,port should be opened and listened.Also , check from the application side that uses this port.

Comment: It is, I'll update the question

Comment: yes sorry my bad , you already mentioned , its access from different servers..

Comment: `127.0.0.1:6379` means its listening for connections coming from `localhost` only - you'll need to configure your service to listen on `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: True, I just figured this out, I just opened redis config to bind 0.0.0.0 and it worked. you can post it as an answer.